# Wrapping buttons one below the other if text content width exceeds available width

Tags: ios, autolayout, word-wrap

I am currently searching for a solution to do the following:

Normally I have to buttons next to each other with equal width and a bit of spacing.

```
---------------------------    ---------------------------
| a bit of text           |    | also a bit of text      |
---------------------------    ---------------------------
```

But if the text of one of the buttons is too long to be displayed in the available width

```
---------------------------    ---------------------------
| too much text for this width | also a bit of text      |
---------------------------    ---------------------------
```

I would like to automatically let them wrap one below the other and have them the full available width

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| too much text for this width                           |
----------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------
| also a bit of text                                     |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I played around a bit width different combinations of constraints and content compression resistance, but it never worked like I wanted it to.

Does anybody have an idea or a solution for that? I appreciate any help!

Comment: You would have to enter a for loop around it to lay the button and calculate the text length and lay the button accordingly.

Are you working with Xib and auto constraints?

Comment: Its possible to do this with storyboard and little code, but you need 2 `also a bit of text ` button, one is next to the first button, second below it, and set their height/width based on the first button to show/hide them, else can do coding way and place them manually

Comment: @gurmandeep yes, I am working with Xib and auto layout constraints. What would be the best way to calculate the width the button will need for its text?

Comment: The app is for iPhone/ iPad or Universal?

Comment: Then i think you need to make the code for iPhone's and not iPad. Do one thing when you are adding the button. Make a for loop and set the frame according to the text length

Comment: Could you post some code? Or part of your storyboard at least?